# how to predict second class which is more close to test data

Tags: opencv, svm

I am using opencv-2.4 (`CvSVM`) for classification. For each test data it is predicting one class as predicted output. But I need to find the next class which is more close to the test data.
Is there any way to find that in opencv SVM classifier ??

Comment: There's an option to get the signed DF value in `predict()`. Is that what you want?

Comment: No, Suppose I have a test data, and SVM is predicted that it belongs t0 the class `5`. The next class which is is more close to the same test data may be `S`. So I need to find this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can not do it directly with the current interface. 
One solution would be to use the library [libsvm](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) instead.

You may do it in opencv, but it will require a little bit of work.

First, you must know that OpenCV uses a ["1-against-1"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification#One-vs.-one) strategy for multi-class classification. 
For a N-class problem, it will train N*(N-1)/2 binary classifier (one for each couple of classes), and then uses a majority vote to choose the most probable class.

You will have to apply each classifier, and do the majority yourself to get what you want.

The code below show you how to do that with OpenCV 3 (warning: it is untested, probably contains errors, but it gives you a good starting point).

```
Ptr<SVM> svm;
int N;            //number of classes
Mat data;         //input data to classify

Mat sv=svm->getSupportVectors();
Ptr<Kernel> kernel=svm->getKernel();
Mat buffer(1,sv.rows,CV_32F);
kernel->calc(sv.rows, sv.cols , sv.ptr<float>(), data.ptr<float>(), buffer.ptr<float>());  // apply kernel on data (CV_32F vector) and support vectors

Mat alpha, svidx;
vector<int> votes(N, 0);  // results of majority vote will be stored here

int i, j, dfi;
for( i = dfi = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
{
    for( j = i+1; j < N; j++, dfi++ )
    {
        // compute score for each binary svm
        double rho=svm->getDecisionFunction(dfi, alpha, svidx);
        double sum = -rho;
        for( k = 0; k < sv.rows; k++ )
            sum += alpha.at<float>(k)*buffer.at<float>(svidx.at<int>(k));
        // majority vote
        votes[sum > 0 ? i : j]++;
    }
}
```

Edit: This code is adapted from the internal code of Opencv [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.2.0/modules/ml/src/svm.cpp#L1886).
It is incorrect, as pointed out by David Doria in the comments, since there is no getKernel function defined in the SVM class. I still leave it here, since it should'nt be too difficult to modify the internal OpenCV code to add it, and there is apparently no other way to do it.

Comment: getDecisionFunction() is available in opencv ??

Comment: You are right, it is not available in opencv 2.4, i did use the git version. It is available in opencv 3.0 beta, though. I don't think it is possible to do it in opencv2.4 without modifying the internal of the library.

Comment: Of course, you may also train yourself the binary classifiers, using 1-vs-1 or 1-vs-rest strategy.

Comment: @AdrienDescamps I think `vote[...]` is also supposed to be `votes[...]`? Can you also explain the sum that is happening? Why does it start at `-rho`? Am I also correct that you are just calculating the number of votes for each class, leaving it up to the original poster to take the index with the second largest value to really answer his question?

Comment: @AdrienDescamps `getKernel()` doesn't seem to be a member of `SVM` anymore? http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html

Comment: @David Doria You are right, there is no `getKernel` function. I have added a comment to clarify, and fixed the other mistakes. Thanks for pointing this out.