# OpenCV unable to set up SVM Parameters

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, svm, opencv3.0

I have just started my learning on SVM using C++ OpenCV and was referring to the SVM documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/ml/introduction_to_svm/introduction_to_svm.html). I wanted to try out the sample source code from the link to get familiar with it first but I couldn't run the sample source code. It returns the error :

> Error 1   error C2065: 'CvSVMParams' : undeclared identifier

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 with OpenCV 3.0.0. The setup process should be correct as all other codes are working well except this.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm getting this error now: error C2039: 'Params' : is not a member of 'cv::ml::SVM'

Comment: Can you please show some code?

Comment: Sorry, but I have only copied the exact same sample source code from [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/ml/introduction_to_svm/introduction_to_svm.html)

Comment: Probably that sample is outdated too... Set parameters like I did in my answer to the question I linked, i.e. `svm->setType(SVM::C_SVC);`, etc...

Comment: Ok, it's probably non trivial, I'll add an answer

Comment: Thanks. In that case, what should the value for the SVM parameters be during the training? As referred to the documentation,
C++: bool CvSVM::train(const Mat& trainData, const Mat& responses, const Mat& varIdx=Mat(), const Mat& sampleIdx=Mat(), CvSVMParams params=CvSVMParams() )

Comment: As shown in the example, you can use `trainAuto` to find optimal parameters.

Comment: Just wondering, will any XML file be generated in this case? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, but you need to save after `trainAuto` to have to correct parameters

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get it. Mind providing some examples?

Comment: add `svm->write(FileStorage("test.xml", FileStorage::WRITE));` after you trained the svm with either `svm->train(...)` or `svm->trainAuto(...)`

Comment: Very clear explanations. Many thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A lot of things changed [from OpenCV 2.4 to OpenCV 3.0](http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/dfa/tutorial_transition_guide.html#gsc.tab=0). Among others, the machine learning module, which isn't backward compatible.

This is the OpenCV [tutorial code for the SVM](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/ml/introduction_to_svm/introduction_to_svm.html), update for OpenCV 3.0:

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/ml.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::ml;

int main(int, char**)
{
    // Data for visual representation
    int width = 512, height = 512;
    Mat image = Mat::zeros(height, width, CV_8UC3);

    // Set up training data
    int labels[4] = { 1, -1, -1, -1 };
    Mat labelsMat(4, 1, CV_32SC1, labels);

    float trainingData[4][2] = { { 501, 10 }, { 255, 10 }, { 501, 255 }, { 10, 501 } };
    Mat trainingDataMat(4, 2, CV_32FC1, trainingData);

    // Set up SVM's parameters
    Ptr<SVM> svm = SVM::create();
    svm->setType(SVM::C_SVC);
    svm->setKernel(SVM::LINEAR);
    svm->setTermCriteria(TermCriteria(TermCriteria::MAX_ITER, 100, 1e-6));

    // Train the SVM with given parameters
    Ptr<TrainData> td = TrainData::create(trainingDataMat, ROW_SAMPLE, labelsMat);
    svm->train(td);

    // Or train the SVM with optimal parameters
    //svm->trainAuto(td);

    Vec3b green(0, 255, 0), blue(255, 0, 0);
    // Show the decision regions given by the SVM
    for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; ++j)
        {
            Mat sampleMat = (Mat_<float>(1, 2) << j, i);
            float response = svm->predict(sampleMat);

            if (response == 1)
                image.at<Vec3b>(i, j) = green;
            else if (response == -1)
                image.at<Vec3b>(i, j) = blue;
        }

    // Show the training data
    int thickness = -1;
    int lineType = 8;
    circle(image, Point(501, 10), 5, Scalar(0, 0, 0), thickness, lineType);
    circle(image, Point(255, 10), 5, Scalar(255, 255, 255), thickness, lineType);
    circle(image, Point(501, 255), 5, Scalar(255, 255, 255), thickness, lineType);
    circle(image, Point(10, 501), 5, Scalar(255, 255, 255), thickness, lineType);

    // Show support vectors
    thickness = 2;
    lineType = 8;
    Mat sv = svm->getSupportVectors();

    for (int i = 0; i < sv.rows; ++i)
    {
        const float* v = sv.ptr<float>(i);
        circle(image, Point((int)v[0], (int)v[1]), 6, Scalar(128, 128, 128), thickness, lineType);
    }

    imwrite("result.png", image);        // save the image

    imshow("SVM Simple Example", image); // show it to the user
    waitKey(0);

}
```

The output should look like:

[image]

Comment: if I had two negative and positive data set how can I train those data set for SVM

Comment: @Miki Thanks - it's always so hard to find these new things as search engines have so much of the old ways demonstrated! I modified this to show which things were in which namespace explicitly, as well as linked the drawing to the actual data instead of duplicating it: https://gist.github.com/daviddoria/943b82f1877f4ed3541544c48c22926d

Comment: @Miki Is there a reason that we can't create an SVM object on the stack? I looked at `svm.cpp` and `create()` just returns an `SVMImpl`, but this is hidden on purpose, I guess because that's the point of PIMPL? Just trying to confirm my understanding :)

Comment: @Miki I tried `trainAuto` (vs `train`) and found that `response` was zero everywhere that it was `-1` when using `train`. The output image looks like same, except the large blue region has turned black (as the image is initialized to zero). Is this expected?

Comment: Hi @David ! I'll check tomorrow.. or on Monday ;D thanks for the edit! (To my understanding is to fit the "Algorithm" interface. And yes, pimpl.. not meant to be used outside the class)

Comment: @Miki Great, thanks. Also, the support vector seem to be drawn strangely... just a circle at `(0,0)` (that appears as a gray quarter-circle in the very top left of the image)? The actual value is `(-0.00813008 0.00816326)`.

Comment: @Miki This is actually probably an even better way to demonstrate it so the data only lives in OpenCV structures and removes the constexpr requirement of the array sizes: https://gist.github.com/daviddoria/36032bbd699a07f38b6a982a78dafc1c

Comment: @Miki I don't suppose you had a few minutes to look at this :) ?

Comment: Oh sh*t, completely forgot... ;) I'll check asap @david

Comment: @Miki If you get on a roll and want to clean up this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27865939/how-to-predict-second-class-which-is-more-close-to-test-data/27874882#comment70262581_27874882 that'd be very helpful too :) The internet doesn't seem to know how to get a "score/confidence/probability" out of the OpenCV3 SVM!

Comment: Hi @David! Well... 1) the support vectors are not correct. This seems to be [an unresolved bug](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/4897). 2) With OpenCV 3.0 I get in fact 0 values (trainAuto) instead of -1 (train). With OpenCV 3.2 it always gives -1. It was [a bug that is now corrected](http://code.opencv.org/issues/4464)

Comment: @David, for the other question, are you looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33319975/5008845)?

Answer (score 0):

I found the code above worked but I  needed to make a small modification to convert the labels to integers. The modification is  in bold:

```
// Set up training data **Original**:

int labels[4] = { 1, -1, -1, -1 };

Mat labelsMat(4, 1, **CV_32SC1**, labels);

// Set up training data **Modified**:

int labels[4] = { 1, -1, -1, -1 };

Mat labelsMat(4, 1, **CV_32S**, labels);
```

Comment: Why did you need to do this?

Comment: From what I member the class label was  a double or the feature matrix was a int. This was over 6 mouths ago so its kind of hazzy

Comment: `CV_32S` and `CV_32SC1` makes no difference given how the constructor is being called. They both mean the same thing here.