# Using SVM and BOW for image classification OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

Im trying to implement an image classification program using the BoW to create the visual library and classify using SVM. Now I have done the Bow part and I'm kinda stuck with the SVM training part.

This is what I have coded so far.

1) Extract (detect and describe) features from training images. (I have 4 classes of images)
2) Build a unclustered matrix of all features of the training images
3) Use k-mean clustering to cluster the data into bags (BoW)
5) Save the visual library in YML format for accessing by the SVM predictor
4) Build a BoW descriptor incorporated with SIFT and FLANN to extract features from the test image
5) Build SVM classifier

No my question is how to train the SVM classifier before I proceed with actual prediction.

According OpenCV 3.1 (not 2.4) class reference for SVM,
[image]

We can train the classifier using the trainAuto() member function. In order to create the data for training we have to use the one of following member functions.
[image]
[image]

Now having said that, I prefer to use the Train::create function to create the training data. What are the arguments of TrainData::create() member function. How do I build these arguments for my case where training images are all in the same directory separated by folders. What do arguments layout, responses, varldx, sampleldx, sampleWeights and varType mean? Sorry if I'm asking a basic question. Im new to openCv and I don't find sufficient help for the OpenCV 3.1 on the internet. All the materials I find are related to OpenCV 2.4. OpenCV 3.1 is big overhaul compared to the former version. Furthermore the documentation for 3.1 is in beta stage and does not help much either. Thank you. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can start from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33899407/5008845). It's a complete example on how to use SVM with OpenCV 3 and shows you how to use `TrainData`

Comment: Hey @Miki thank you for the answer. I looked at the example before. Its a very primitive example doesn't help in my case much. Because mine is a set of images of different classes, so its not clear how to for the create matrix argument (since not I'm not sure what data goes in the columns of the argument matrix) for the TrainData::create() function

Comment: Referring to the linked code, each row of `trainingDataMat` will contain a point, and the corresponding row of `labelsMat` will contain the label for that point. In you case, a point is the BoW histogram for an image, and the label is the class of that image.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Miki I really appreciate your help. I was able to code mine. Thanks again