# SVM Training Data Error

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

i'm using Opencv 3.0 and i tried this code  but i'm getting this error :

```
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::ml;
int main(int argc, char** argv){
 int labels[10] = { 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0};
 cv::Mat lablesMat(10, 1, CV_32SC1, labels);

 float trainingData[10][2] = { { 100, 10 }, { 150, 10 }, { 600, 200 }, { 600, 10 }, { 10, 100 }, { 455, 10 }, { 345, 255 }, { 10, 501`z` }, { 401, 255 }, { 30, 150 } };

 cv::Mat trainDataMat(10, 2, CV_32FC1, trainingData);
SVM::Params params;
    params.svmType    = SVM::C_SVC;
    params.kernelType = SVM::LINEAR;
    params.termCrit   = TermCriteria(TermCriteria::MAX_ITER, 100, 1e-6);
    // Train the SVM
    Ptr<SVM> svm = StatModel::train<SVM>(trainDataMat, ROW_SAMPLE, lablesMat, params);
 //Create test features
 float testData[2] = { 150, 15 };

 cv::Mat testDataMat(2, 1, CV_32FC1, testData);

 //Predict the class labele for test data sample
 float predictLable = svm->predict(testDataMat);

 std::cout << "Predicted label :" << predictLable << "\n";
    return(0);
}
```

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (samples.cols == var_count && samples.type() == CV_32F) in predict,
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():   error: (-215) samples.cols == var_count && samples.type() == CV_32F in function predict

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV unable to set up SVM Parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33897803/opencv-unable-to-set-up-svm-parameters)

Comment: Please have a look at my answer there. This won't even compile on OpenCV 3.0, since `SVM::Params` doesn't exists anymore.

Comment: no it did compile i got this probleme in the execution.

Comment: when i use the other code i get this error :

Comment: : ‘class cv::ml::SVM’ has no member named ‘setType’ svm->setType(ml::SVM::C_SVC);
‘class cv::ml::SVM’ has no member named ‘setKernel’ svm->setKernel(ml::SVM::LINEAR);

Comment: Then you're not using OpenCV 3.0

Comment: yes i'm using opencv 3.0

Comment: You're probably using opencv 3.0 **beta**... Don't use that anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was that the test vector should have 1 row, and 2 cols

```
 cv::Mat testDataMat(1, 2, CV_32FC1, testData);
```