# OpenCV 3 and SVM training

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

I already searched for this type of error but I did not find anything similar...

My question is related to opencv3 and SVM. Basically, I have this:

```
int labels[2] = {1, -1};
Mat labelsMat(2, 1, CV_32S, labels);
float trainingData[2][2] = { { 501, 10 }, { 255, 10 } };
Mat training_samples(2, 2, CV_64FC1, trainingData);

...

training_samples.convertTo(training_samples, CV_32S);
labelsMat.convertTo(labelsMat, CV_32F);
Ptr<ml::SVM> svm = ml::SVM::create();
svm->setType(ml::SVM::C_SVC);
svm->setKernel(ml::SVM::LINEAR);
svm->setC(1); 
svm->train(training_samples, ml::SampleTypes::ROW_SAMPLE, labelsMat);
```

When I compile, I get this error:

> OpenCV Error: Bad argument (in the case of classification problem the responses must be categorical; either specify varType when creating TrainData, or pass integer responses) in train, file /home/develop/_Morpheos/opencv/opencv/modules/ml/src/svm.cpp, line 1618 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception' what(): /home/develop/_Morpheos/opencv/opencv/modules/ml/src/svm.cpp:1618: error: (-5) in the case of classification problem the responses must be categorical; either specify varType when creating TrainData, or pass integer responses in function train

I tried almost everything but I do not catch the error.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CV_64F` means `double`, but you need `float`, i.e. `CV_32F`. Use:

```
// Change me!
Mat training_samples(2, 2, CV_32FC1, trainingData);
```

Also there's no need to convert to integer type, so you can remove the line:

```
// Remove me!
training_samples.convertTo(training_samples, CV_32S);
```

And labels should be of integer type in classification, so remove also:

```
// Remove me!
labelsMat.convertTo(labelsMat, CV_32F);
```

---

You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33899407/5008845) for a complete example.

Comment: Thanks Miki....another question: in openCV there are not normalization rules for data before doing SVM training and testing ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of

Comment: For your normalization question, this would be done internally depending on the type of the image you give, example float will be in the range 0 to 1. The value you get from the `predict` will also lie in this range.

Comment: @Rick that's not correct. Float images are in fact in range 0,1.. but you can give the svm any value you want. The predict will be an integer corresponding to the class. Also I think that OP is referring to feature scaling, which I think is supported in OpenCV (since it's based on libsvm) but I never i investigated so I can't tell for sure. It's fairly trivial to implement, however

Comment: @alex probably I wasn't clear before. I think opencv applies feature scaling internally... I'm not aware of any configurable normalization rule

Comment: @Miki hmm when I used the SVM from OpenCV, I was normalizing the training and label mats to get the predicted values not as a class but rather as a value between 0-1 which corresponded to the intensity of the channel, so I'm not sure if we are talking about the same thing ;)

Comment: @RickM. you were probably using it in regression to predict a pixel value. But that is just a specific application, you're not bounded to it. And here the OP's using the SVM in classification

Comment: Yes in fact it was for regression. I get it now :)

Comment: Ok guys, thanks a lot for your answers....finally, just to be sure, I apply a mean/std normalization to my data before doind training and apply the same values to test. It seems it works well