# How can I get the Kernel of a SVM classifier in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, kernel, svm

I developed a multi-class SVM with OpenCV 3.0 and I want to compute the distance between each class and data (input) in order to estimate the confidence of the prediction.

I used the below code at [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27865939/how-to-predict-second-class-which-is-more-close-to-test-data) but I have errors when I try to get the Kernel of my SVM!

Thanks for your help.

```
    Mat sv = svm->getSupportVectors();
    Ptr<SVM::Kernel> kernel = svm->getKernel(); // ??
    Mat buffer(1, sv.rows, CV_32F);
    kernel->calc(sv.rows, sv.cols, sv.ptr<float>(), data.ptr<float>(), buffer.ptr<float>());  // apply kernel on data (CV_32F vector) and support vectors

    Mat alpha, svidx;
    int N = 11;

    vector<int> votes(N, 0);  // results of majority vote will be stored here (N is number of classes)

    int i, j, dfi;
    for (i = dfi = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < N; j++, dfi++)
        {
            // compute score for each binary svm
            double rho = svm->getDecisionFunction(dfi, alpha, svidx);
            double sum = -rho;
            for (int k = 0; k < sv.rows; k++)
                sum += alpha.at<float>(k)*buffer.at<float>(sv.at<int>(k));
            // majority vote
            votes[sum > 0 ? i : j]++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the error? Please post the exact error message.

Comment: You are right, there is no way to access the svm kernel in the current opencv version (3.2). It was an error in my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27865939/how-to-predict-second-class-which-is-more-close-to-test-data, i have added a note to clarify now. Sorry for the confusion. Btw, you should have posted it as a comment in the original question, not as a separate question, because i was not aware of this post until i found it by chance.